# Call method, defined in Application controller, in other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, I have a method named `to_slug` defined in `application_controller.rb` and I want to invoque that in my controllers but I have this error:

```
undefined method `to_slug' for "Probando slug automático":String
```

This is my `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :to_slug

  include CanCan::ControllerAdditions

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def to_slug
    ret = self.strip
    ret.gsub! /['`]/,""
    ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
    ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "
    ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]\s*/, '_'
    ret.gsub! /_+/,"_"
    ret.gsub! /\A[_\.]+|[_\.]+\z/,""
    ret
  end
end
```

And in my `debates_controller.rb` (no all controller :) ):

```
class DebatesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @debate = Debate.new(debate_params)
    @debate.slug = @debate.title.to_slug
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method defined on the `ApplicationController` is available on all  your controller instances, so you can call it like this:

```
class DebatesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    to_slug
  end
end
```

But that doesn't make much sense for your method logic. To make it available on the `String` class instances you need to reopen the `String` class and add the `to_slug` method there.

Define your method like this:

```
class String
  def to_slug
    ret = self.strip
    ret.gsub! /['`]/,""
    ret.gsub! /\s*@\s*/, " at "
    ret.gsub! /\s*&\s*/, " and "
    ret.gsub! /\s*[^A-Za-z0-9\.\-]\s*/, '_'
    ret.gsub! /_+/,"_"
    ret.gsub! /\A[_\.]+|[_\.]+\z/,""
    ret
  end
end
```

After that, use it anywhere in the app:

```
@debate.slug = @debate.title.to_slug
```

Comment: Ok, but (sorry for my lack of knowledge :( ) where I need to put the `string.rb` file or where I must define that method?

Comment: You can put it anywhere (even at the bottom of the `application_controller.rb` will work).

Comment: Or it would be nicer to put it somewhere into the `lib/extensions.rb`, and then add the `require 'extensions'` into your `application_controller.rb`